# Errors when use TextField in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am beginner in flutter and trying to make a simple app.
When add textfield in flutter and debug app on device i get the error below:

```
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported, use openfile
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:151)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:705)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1689)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1627)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:337)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin.access$700(PlatformPlugin.java:28)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformPlugin$1.getClipboardData(PlatformPlugin.java:107)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformChannel.java:141)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7403)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform( 6021):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Here is my `flutter doctor` output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.26.0-18.0.pre.210, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720], locale tr-TR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.53.0)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
```

And source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Test App'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Phone',
            prefixIcon: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 12.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.smartphone),
            ),
          ),
          onSubmitted: (String value) {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to use latest flutter stable version (1.22.6) and latest dev version (1.26.0-17.2.pre) also, but got same error again. How can i fix this error?

**UPDATE**

I tried using emulator instead of device and didn't get those error. So i tried on device again and it solved. I don't know how this resolve error or it is really the reason of the solution but for now it works.

Comment: Is the app crashing?

Comment: Doesn't but input doesn't work, and on VS Code side it throws PlatformException and pauses application.

Comment: try a flutter clean, then run again

Comment: it did not solve, still getting error

Comment: Try 2 things: 1)  Uninstall the app on the device and try again 2) Remove the visualDensity property from the ThemeData.

Comment: Nope it didn't help either

Comment: What plugins do you have installed?

Comment: None, i only changed main.dart file after create app, id did npt install any other packages. But if you asked VS Code plugins, then only Flutter and Dart plugins

Comment: I have this exact same problem, any updates?

Comment: This is a known bug in Flutter.
See: [Can't paste into TextField when copying from Samsung Notes, MS Word and MS Excel on Android](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74320) You could upvote the issue, maybe they will fix it.